# Magento controller action return gateway timeout error

Tags: magento-1.9, php-5.6

I have created a controller action in my custom module controller class, there is a loop of all products to do some functionality, but after 5 minutes it return 504 gateway timeout error.

For this I made changes in php.ini and  in .htaccess

```
// in php.ini
always_populate_raw_post_data = -1
max_execution_time = 259200
memory_limit = 2048M;
post_max_size = 32M;

// in htaccess
php_value memory_limit 3072M
php_value max_execution_time 259200
php_value max_input_time 259200
```

and `phpinfo()` also showing updated value for above. but even after this the process return gateway timeout error after 5 minutes.

How to resolve this? 
Is there any other parameter to increased execution time which I missed?

OR Is there any method to increase execution time for only my controller action?

Comment: 5 minutes on frontend are you serious???

Comment: No I have added a action for some functionality in admin.

Comment: just set that functionality in cron

Comment: No, I can't. In admin there is a button, on click that button all products gets export in CSV with some custom filter and it is client requirement.

Comment: If there are no other options you can rewrite your code to direct access to db it's will beat faster

Comment: Is there any way to increase `max_execustion_time` only for my controller action, because when I try same code from external file then it is working, but when I try from controller action then it breaks after `300 seconds`.